Kubectl ingress does not let access to the internet due to timeout error
I am trying to use ingress to make a pretty basic flask application reachable via internet.
First, I installed and enabled Ingress-Nginx
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.11.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
minikube addons enable ingress

Second, I used the following configuration for my pretty basic Flask application
hello-everything.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: hello-replica-set
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: pythonincontainers/simple-flask:v1.1
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: "1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /  
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-service
            port: 
              number: 5000

I used kubectl describe ingress command, and I get
Name:             hello-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.49.2
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /   hello-service:5000 (10.244.0.64:5000)
Annotations:  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                  From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                 ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    4m3s (x2 over 5m3s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync

I also used minikube ip to get the minikube VMs IP address, but I cannot get access to the internet due to timeout error.
I would really appreciate any help or suggestion to tackle this issue.
Further details:
kubectl version

Client Version: v1.30.4
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.30.0

Everything works fine if I use plain Docker instead. In addition to that I also checked the logs of the hello-replica-set in kubernetes dashboard and I get
 * Serving Flask app "hello" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)


If you run the same image in plain Docker, can you reach it?  (There's a common Flask setup problem that can result in a containerized service being unreachable, and you'd have the same problems in Kubernetes and a simpler plain-Docker environment.)

Good point. I can reach it using plain Docker. This is the main reason I am so confused.
